# Best workflow to save an image in 3 different sizes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow

In Photoshop, I want to create 3 different sizes of the same logo.  There will be some differences in the look of the logo depending on target screen size.

I believe the slice tool is what I want but I'm not sure.  I've been learning more about the slice tool.  It seems if I use it for creating differently sized logos, it will save lots of time as everything can be saved at once.  This way, I don't have to create three different images with three different saves.

Is the slice tool the most efficient way to handle the above scenario?

Comment: The slice tool is **not** the tool you need. The slice tool is used to **divide** one image into many images, not resize one image. You need to actually resize the file via Image > Image Size. For what it's worth, logos should be created in a vector application, not Photoshop.

Comment: I suppose you could create an image with 3 separate iterations of the log and then use the slice tool to define each area of the image. Seems like a cumbersome workflow to me though.

Comment: @Scott - Can't you accomplish the same thing by placing all three images on the same pallet, slicing them and saving?  Isn't one save better than 3? Besides, as I mentioned above, there are slight differences in each image.

Comment: @Scott - interesting. I was thinking the method you pointed out was cumbersome.

Comment: Beat you by 13 seconds :) For me 3 files would be better and more reliable. I'd know I'm working on the correct file when needed. A logo should be created once then pretty much never touched again. Wouldn't you want 3 files to be able to place each instance independently of the others?

Comment: Maybe logo is a bad example.  Let's just say some image.  When you change that one image, you will always update 3 images.  In regards to your question, they are 3 independent files.  You have the main PSD with 3 images.  When you update/save, it outputs all 3 sizes.  Great workflow and very fast.  Why would you want to open 3 different files every time you need to update one image when you can open one file and get the same result?  You wouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally have them in the same workspace, and as you mention I'd slice them for saving.

Only difference with the comments is, I'd also have each image in a separate smart object. That way, you can edit them freely in a different 'file' so to say, but see the results in comparison with the other two in the same canvas. I'm guessing this might be something similar to what you are looking for because I'm assuming you want to work with pixel perfection for the smaller ones (might be wrong!).

If the logos are very similar between them, I'd have *more* [smart Objects](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/smart-objects/) ("yo dawg, I heard you like smart Objects so I put your smart Objects inside other smartObjects"). You could have a basic one that is common to all of them, and then different styles drawn on top of it fit each version.

Workflow:

- In a new document, create three copies of you image
- Convert each one into a separate Smart Object
- Create slices for each logo size
- Double click on a Smart Object will open it up for you, so you can edit it. Clicking save on the newly opened document will apply the changes you just made to the one in the main document.

Comment: Nice.  I need to read more about smart objects.  Do you know of any tutorials showing the specific workflow you mention above?

Comment: Think I see what you have.  Does this sound right: 3 images in one PSD as smart objects.  Double click a smart object, which opens a new PSD with only that object. Edit newly opened PSD and it also edits just that one smart object.  Save smart object PSD for web.  I think it is an ok workflow and much better than opening 3 files...although you kind of end up opening them anyways.  Is it possible to edit and have that cascade to all smart objects instead of just one?  This would be in case you want to edit a common element (i.e., color).

Comment: @4thSpace For example: 1. Select your image(s). 2. Convert to smart object. 3. Duplicate that smart object ctrl + j ( cmd on mac ). 4. Downsize the duplicated smart object and repeat 3 and 4 as many times as needed. Later on double click any of those to edit the content and press ctrl + s ( cmd on mac )... -- as an example: https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Photoshop-Image-Framer-Export-Script this sort of follows the same idea, except the file saving is handled by a script. You basically open the top smartobject to make changes, then save it and go back to the original doc and run the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, that script doesn't work.  It just throws an element not found error after you type in a name on save.  That script aside, you still will need to save all versions of the file.  But at least you can open the one main PSD rather than opening all of those different versions...right?  Is that the main takeaway?

Comment: @4thSpace I'm thinking you used the script in any random file. Unfortunately it is somewhat tied to the template files that are included, as it is made for a very specific task. -- I was kinda in a hurry, so I didn't explain myself well, I just posted that to kind of show how this could be done. -- Basically without any script you can make slices around the images and then save the original document with Save for web & devices. Just take the slice tool and "draw" boxes around your images and when you save with Save for web & devices, it creates image for each slice.

Comment: You could use this extension http://www.dezignmatterz.com/photoshop-plugins-and-tools/cutslide_photoshop_plugin/ to save the files ( as slices can be a bit cumbersome... ) or if you have mac: http://macrabbit.com/slicy/ -- I have been thinking about making that script of mine more universal, but my priorities have been elsewhere for now.

Comment: Slicy looks awesome and I think it's the answer.  Have you tried it?  I'd rather use it over other tools since MacRabbit is so well known and should have good support.

Comment: @4thSpace oh yeah, I bought slicy right away. I love it. You might want to try the trial before buying it, just to be sure. In here you can get example psd which showcases the features pretty well http://macrabbit.com/slicy/help/ --  That script of mine that I was talking earlier... The template files actually follow the slicy naming system / workflow so closely, that you can pretty muc drop it in slicy and it will be able so save it by using that. Actually that reminds me of one feature that is kinda never mentioned in slicy website. You can create folders by just adding that to the layer.

Comment: E.g. Myfolder/myimage.jpg -- I have the biggest love towards the autosave feature, which re-saves the images after every photoshop file save. -- One thing about this website. You might want to consider writing @name in the message, to make sure they get a notification of your message

Comment: @Joonas This script/extension discussion would make a really good answer. Why don't you post it as one? Might be really helpful for others in the same situation. Oh! And you are also more than welcome to continue it in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner), it's quite active nowadays :)

Answer (score 2):

This could also be done in Illustrator (inspired by the answers [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/12868/8708)):

### If the original artwork is vector...

#### 1. Convert your artwork to a Symbol

Put your artwork on your main artboard. Select all of the artwork, then hit the New Symbol button on the `Symbols` pane (alternatively you can drag the selected artwork to the `Symbols` pane). That will convert your artwork to a symbol.

#### 2. Create a set of artboards, one for each output size you want.

I've got 3 artboards of varying sizes. Each just has the symbol that I've made from the SE logo.  Then, from the `Symbols` pane, drag out your artwork and place it on the other artboards (and resize it as you like)

[image: Illustrator]

#### 3. Edit the logo as needed

To edit the logo, just double click the symbols on the `Symbols` pane:

[image: Edit Symbol]

When done editing, hit escape and all the instances of the symbol will get updated:

[image: Updated Symbol]

#### 4. Export the artwork

The exporting part is where Illustrator's power play comes into effect.

`File` → `Export...` as PNG, make sure you `Use Artboards` (all):

[image: Export Logo]

The artboards and your resolutions will all be automatically saved based on the artboard name.

---

### If the original artwork is from Photoshop...

Very similar set up, just ignore the symbols part. Instead, use `File` → `Place...` and place the .PSD into the document as many times as you have artboards. You can still update the artwork in Photoshop. Every time you save it in PS, Illustrator will ask if you'd like to update it:

[image: Update Links]

However, at this point I'd probably go with Yisela's solution instead. No need to split the workflow up between two different programs.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cutandslice.me/ might be helpful - ?! - free plugin.
if you are dev'ing for android and need the exact same img in xhdpi hdpi mdpi then it looks like this plugin would work for you (read the page before using....   you have to specifically name layers with certain syntax like adding # before then name for it to work properly.